# Как заставить ie отреагировать миганием при открытии вкладки на панели задач

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, javascript, браузер

Имеется некоторая страница, на ней отображается окно с сообщениями. Возможно ли каким то способом при появлении нового сообщения оповестить пользователя при свернутых окнах ie,например мигание иконки браузера (ie) на панели задач? Причем мигание срабатывает при передаче фокуса когда открыто окно. В случае с открытыми вкладками ничего не происходит. Как можно заставить его мигает?

Comment: http://adodson.com/notification.js/ ie9 может flash taskbar icon

Comment: я ещё сто лет назад favicon переключал, чтобы алерт показать в мониторинге.

Answer (score 2):

Врядли, я лично таких реализаций не видел и очень сомневаюсь, что такое возможно, если бы браузер позволял настолько глубоко управлять системой, то это был бы, простите, полный 3.14здец. Вы только представльте какие возможности бы появились у вирусописателей? :) Фуфуфу, даже и не мечтайте об этом :)

По теме, можно попробовать выводить сообщение через `alert()`, вроде тогда будет мигать в таске окошко браузера. Других идей нету.

Comment: а какие нибудь другие альтернативные варианты привлечения внимания пользователя есть? какими средствами это можно добиться?

Comment: Можно, например вот так
    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML='СМОТРИ СЮДА';
и по setInterval (http://javascript.ru/setInterval) менять надпись с задержкой

Comment: Ну как вариант еще предложенное @fleg тоже можно. а так, можно еще какойнить flash использовать со звуком, но по мне так излишне.

зыж поправлю последнее: не излишне, а лучше так не надо, это плохая практика. :)

Comment: флеш со звуком для привлечения внимания? вот это самое плохое. Сидишь себе вечером, слушаешь музыку, работаешь. И тут какой то странице захотелось "привлечь внимание". Можно и инфаркт словить.

Недавно писали о человеке, который оставил комп и лег спать. Тот в 3 часа ночи решил накатить обновления и обновиться. Восстановил броузер, который открыл страницу, где было видео с криками монстров.  Памперсы наверно поменял:)

Хочется привлечь пользователя? пользуйтесь нативными приложениями, долгоживущим приложениям в браузере не место.

Comment: ну про флеш я имел ввиду, что это плохо. :) спасибо за замечание. Ну и про нативные приложения тоже верно, их не упоминал, поскольку задачи такой небыло поставлено.

из других вариантов вижу только еще послать человеку смс/ммс/почту и всяое такое.

Comment: некоторые браузеры, например хром, могут показывать всплывющие подсказки. В некоторых случаях - самое оно. Может ли такое делать ИЕ - не знаю.

Comment: М? всплывающие подсказки где? 
УПД: А, @eicto ссылку привел.

Comment: задумывалась уже посмотреть в сторону аплетов. Не знаю правда получится или нет

Comment: Ява апплеты? Думаю это тоже не самое хорошее решение, у меня да и у многих они попросту отключены и я не буду их включать ради одного сайта.